# Types of specific positions in array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, go, types

I'm very much a newb in Go and I'm trying to build a function with this general aspect:

```
mapOfResults = ThingDoer([
  ["One",    int,    -1,    true],
  ["Flying", string, "",    true],
  ["Banana", bool,   false, true]
])
```

But I cannot even figure its signature (is signature even the proper term for it in Go? the definition of all its params etc).

I'm talking about this construct:

```
func ThingDoer(config ThisIsWhatICannotFigure) map[string]Results {
    // the body of my function
}
```

How do I define the types for such a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 type ConfigItem struct {
    Name string
    Value interface{}
    SomethingElse bool
 }

mapOfResults = ThingDoer([]ConfigItem{
  {"One",    -1,    true},
  {"Flying", "",    true},
  {"Banana", false, true},
})
```

The ThingDoer can use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) to determine the value types:

```
func ThingDoer(config []ConfigItem) map[foo]bar {
    for _, item := range config {
      switch v := item.Value.(type) {
      case int:
        // v is int
      case bool:
        // v is bool
      case string:
        // v is string
      }
    }
 }
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/1Cbr0X-PlI)

Comment: Works for me! Apparently I have to wait a bit to accept your answer though. Thanks!